# Cannot import google-one-tap types in angular component

Tags: angular, types, google-one-tap

I have installed google-one-tap typings in my angular application, but I cannot use it the component.

I am trying to import it like this:

```
import * as google from 'google-one-tap';
```

Compiler gives me an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'google-one-tap'
```

I have defined `typeRoots` in tsconfig with

```
"node_modules/@types"
```

How to import google-one-tap properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code to include the library.

```js
declare global {
  const google: typeof import('google-one-tap');
}
```